# Add one day to a date and save it as a new variable in Smalltalk

Tags: date, smalltalk, visualworks

so here is the problem. I want to take a date from *lastDate* and put it to *nextDate*, but also add one day to the variable *nextDate*. Anyone know how to do that?

```
| lastDate nextDate |
lastDate := Date 
            newDay: 10
            monthNumber: 5
            year: 2019.
nextDate := lastDate.

HELP HERE

^nextDate
```

Comment: Which dialect of Smalltalk? Have you learned to use the class browser? What methods are implemented in Date? Without knowing anything about the language, what would be the most natural thing to do? Is this a homework assignment for a class? What research have you attempted on your own?

Comment: This is just a semestral project for my uni. We got software programmed by subject's lecturer. I got some fundamentals in Smalltalk, but for me its just another language to learn.

Comment: @MartinDub I doubt the subject's lecturer has coded himself whole smalltalk IDE (that takes years), he probably used some already available like Pharo, Squeak, Dolphin, etc.. I've seen and used many languages, but I think Smalltalk is worth your time and you should invest your time to learn it more (it is not just another language to learn).  What is also important to note - James has deep knowledge of Smalltalk and its internals so you could learn great deal from him.

Comment: You can check yourselves - https://sites.google.com/site/daskalosapplication/instalace/841E6F1AA09E840A3481EE6D5CC7D30EFEB

Comment: @MartinDub could you join me at the chat room?  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209301/room-for-tukan-and-martin-dub.  I have tried it and from the icon I presume it is VisualWorks from Cincom (I have now check with the paper and it is indeed VW - VisualWorks/Smalltalk version 7.4.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know which Smalltalk you are using.

I will use Smalltalk/X-jv branch for the examples as it is easies for me:

```
| lastDate nextDate |

lastDate := Date newDay: 10
                  month: 5
                   year: 2019.

nextDate := lastDate addDays: 1.
^ nextDate
```

To add one day you can use the `#addDays:` message to your `lastDate`.

*Edit: due to comment*

To add a year you can send message `#addYears:`

Comment: And what about adding one year? addYears does not work here.

Comment: I just added 1825 days. Gross, but works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MartinDub That is ugly solution.  To add a year send a message `#addYears:`.

Comment: @MartinDub what does not work?  Does it show any message?  If you check your browser does it show any method?

Comment: Unhandled exception: Message not understood: #addYears.

Comment: @MartinDub Ok, so that message does not exist. What about `#addMonths:`?  Which you could easily take and create your own `#addYears:`.

Comment: Also not. Only `#addDays` work. I will keep it that way and my examiner about the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinDub that is weird.  Anyways, it works somehow.  You are welcome.